# why the type mismatch error?

Tags: excel, vba

Any idea why I'm getting a type mismatch error here? The cursor highlights the second last "&" in the filename string at the bottom of this code. Something to do with the variable dt which is meant to be a date. Any ideas?

Code:

```
Sub daily_report_data()

Dim strpath1 As String
Dim strpath2 As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nm As String
Dim dt() As Date

strpath1 = "\\ironhide\[folder name]\[folder name]\[folder name]\[folder name]\"
strpath2 = "c:\Users\[user.name]\desktop\data files\"

Workbooks.Open Filename:=strpath1 & "[file name].xlsx", ReadOnly:=True

Set wb = Workbooks("[file name]")
Set ws = Workbooks("[file name]").Sheets("data")
nm = ws.Name

dt = Date

Workbooks.Add
DoEvents

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strpath2 & nm & "_" & dt & ".xlsx"
Set wb2 = Workbooks(nm & dt & ".xlsx")
```

Comment: dt returns a date(numeric value) you need to cast that to a string like Format(dt, "mm/dd/yyyy")

Comment: @AGryckiewicz: When you get a correct answer you should mark that as the accepted answer. It will help others reading questions and answers in the future. I see that you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questing yet, but doing so will even give you some reputation points... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared:

```
Dim dt() As Date
```

That's an array. You can't use the "&" string concatenation operator on an array. Just remove the ().

Comment: ok. so the result of the date function is an array? How can I transform the array into something that I can concatenate into the name of my file?

Comment: No, the result of the date function is not an array. Remove the () in the declaration. Why "dt = Date" succeeds, I don't know.

Comment: The result of the Date function is a Date type with the format "mm/dd/yyyy".  In order to use it as part of a file name you'll probably want to format and remove the forward slashes by doing something like Format(dt, "ddmmyyyy")

Comment: @DanByström "dt=Date" Succeeds because it is the equivilent to DateTime.Now

Comment: one last question: any idea why my last "save as" won't work?

Comment: @AGryckiewicz  you should Mark Dan's answer

Comment: @Sorceri: well, I don't get why dt=Date.Now should work eiher, since Date.Now is not an array - how can it be assigned to an array...?

Comment: your right it should have errored out with the array call. I was making reference to Dim dt as Date can be set with dt=date.  Sorry if I mislead anyone.

Comment: Well, anyone who knows the answer to that can feel free to add it here someday... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
Dim FileNPath As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim dt As Date

strDate = Format(dt, "ddmmyyyy")
FileNPath = strpath2 & nm & "_" & strDate & ".xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=FileNPath
```

Comment: Just add those lines into your code where it makes sense.